# Sympy diffgeom: Expressions won't simplify

Tags: python, sympy

Here is the setup, defining a manifold and a local coordinate system (x,y,z).

```
from sympy.diffgeom import (
    Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem, Differential, 
    WedgeProduct, LieDerivative)

from sympy import symbols, simplify

R3 = Manifold('R_3', 3)
U = Patch('U', R3)
cartesian = CoordSystem('xyz', U, symbols('x y z'))

x, y, z = cartesian.base_scalars()
partial_x, partial_y, partial_z = cartesian.base_vectors()
dx, dy, dz = cartesian.base_oneforms()
```

I expect `simplify(WedgeProduct(dx, dy) + WedgeProduct(dy, dx))` to equal 0, but sympy instead reports `dx /\ dy + dy /\ dx`.

Similarly, no simplification occurs when I try to compute the Lie derivative of a simple 2-form with respect to a vector field defined in terms of `partial_x, partial_y, partial_z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you simply need to define the base vectors for the cartesian space and apply those to the `WedgeProduct`.

```py
...
dx, dy, dz = cartesian.base_oneforms()
e_x, e_y, e_z = cartesian.base_vectors()

u = WedgeProduct(dx, dy)(e_x, e_y) + WedgeProduct(dy, dx)(e_x, e_y)

u.simplify()
# returns 0
```

The `sympy` documentation is a bit terse on this, but I think what's happening is that it needs to be explicitly told the vector space in which you're defining your fields/forms, otherwise it doesn't know how to simplify and apply properties like antisymmetry.

Continuing with that logic, for the Lie derivative, you should be able to get it to work if you supply the base vectors for the coordinate system you're working with.

Comment: @Mark did this solve your issue?